# How to solve this problem in Entity Framework migration?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, orm, entity-framework-migrations, appsettings

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider.
>
> Error: Unable to build IHost
>
> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

```
at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalLoggerExtensions.MigrateUsingConnection(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, IMigrator migrator, IRelationalConnection connection)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.\<\>c__DisplayClass0_0.\<.ctor\>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

This is my `appsettings.json` file:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlServer": "Data Source=.\\sql2016;Initial Catalog=Didban;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True",
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I suggest you could re-check the connection string and use the right data source name.